# Unity editor script check if AddComponent would succeed or fail for specified component type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When an object has a Rigidbody, calling `AddComponent<Rigidbody>()` will return null and it will also log a warning message in Console: "*The component Rigidbody can't be added because GameObject already contains the same component.*" Same thing happens when the object has an Image and we call `AddComponent<Text>()`.

In my editor script, I don't want the warning message to appear in the console if AddComponent fails, so **I need to find a way to check if AddComponent will fail for the given component type**. In which case, I'll simply not call AddComponent at all. I couldn't find an Editor API for this query but it's possible that I've missed some internal APIs.

Comment: Afaik such a check does not exist or at least is only happening internally in the underlying backend and is not exposed in the `c#` layer. Best you can do is ignore the log message and use what you already have

Comment: Yes, the log comes from an extern function called *Internal_AddComponentWithType*. I was hoping that someone would suggest a function from Unsupported/UnityEditorInternal classes that would help me with this issue. In the worst case, I'll see if I can tell Unity to ignore some logs somehow.

Comment: `I'll see if I can tell Unity to ignore some logs somehow` tbh I doubt that one even more then maybe eventually finding some internal thing used by the editor you can use via reflection ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround. Unlike *gameObject.AddComponent*, [**ObjectFactory.AddComponent**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ObjectFactory.AddComponent.html) function actually throws an exception when the component can't be added! If I catch the exception and not log it, then it solves my problem. Downsides of this approach are:

- I was actually using *Undo.AddComponent*, so I'll have to destroy the component returned by ObjectFactory (if it doesn't fail) and call Undo.AddComponent afterwards
- *ObjectFactory.AddComponent* won't work for a small list of deprecated components: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/search?q=ExcludeFromObjectFactory

Until a better answer is posted, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score -1):

A handy function from **Component** class is **TryGetComponent**, it could be used as following:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Q69283330 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // if rigidbody component exists, add the result to _rigidbody
        if(TryGetComponent<Rigidbody>(out _rigidbody))
        {
            // do something with it
        }
        else
        {
            _rigidbody = this.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the answer! What about the case where adding Text fails when there is already a Graphic (e.g. Image) attached? Or the case where adding a BoxCollider won't fail even if there is already another BoxCollider?

Comment: What I know is that you can add **[DisallowMultipleComponent]** above the class declaration to prevent multiple components of the same type.

Comment: For the case of built-in components, I think you might need to check every condition a part.

Comment: I'd need a list of all built-in components that don't allow duplicates and would need to maintain this list as Unity evolves. Not to mention the components coming from packages. This isn't a feasible approach IMO.

Comment: I think I answered your request accurately. You said:  **I need to find a way to check if AddComponent will fail for the given component type.**
And that's what the code above does.

But I would agree that you may want another solution for a generic approach.

Comment: @GhAyoub no it does not reliably check that at all .... e.g. it **is** allowed to add `BoxCollider` multiple times to a GameObject .. this is true for many built-in components ... your code fails for those cases .. also you don't check if you can add something - you rather already do it

Comment: @derHugo, do you see that requirement in the question above? It was added in the comments after.

Comment: @GhAyoub the title reads "Unity editor script **check if** AddComponent **would** succeed or fail for specified component type" ... it does not say "How to check if a component already exists on an object and if not add it" ... and the question body says `In my editor script, I don't want the warning message to appear in the console if AddComponent fails` .... so yes I see this requriement has been there from the beginning not only in the comments

Comment: @derHugo, alright, must be not my best day after all xD